# Anchor a row with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, anchor, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to make it so my `UITableView` always has a specific row at the bottom, anchored there.

I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to perform a fetch, and then the regular Apple boilerplate for detecting a merged context change.

What I'd like to do is always have one row at the bottom of the results, "Not What You're Looking For?". How would I do this? I'm comfortable with custom cell types, but I can't get even a cell of the same type to anchor to the bottom.

Code that adds one more row than what is in the fetchedResultsController:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]+1;
}
```

Code for cellForRowForIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifierNormal = @"NormalCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
cell = [tableView CellIdentifierNormal];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NormalCell createCell]autorelease];
    }
// For regular results, go configure the cell. For the extra 'Special Row' at bottom, assign it the Special cell.
if([indexPath indexAtPosition:0] <= [[[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0] numberOfObjects])
     [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
else {
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SpecialCell createCell] autorelease];
    }
    SpecialCell *nc = (SpecialCell*)cell;
    nc.labelFirstLine.text = @"Not What You're Looking For?";
}
return cell;
}
```

This would work if not using a NSFetchedResultsController, but what happens  is that whenever a cell is updated, the method 'configureCell' is being called from the Controller, which knows nothing about SpecialCell.

From - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:......

```
 case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;
```

And here is configureCell:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Configure the cell
// Go get it from coredata
    NormalCell *vc = (NormalCell*)cell;
NormalObject *no = (NormalCell *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
....<ASSIGNMENT TO CELL HERE>....
```

}

Comment: for better answer please post the code of `cellForRowAtIndex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when you are creating cell for different rows from array, then keep the condition that if it reaches the end of array then you add your custom cell with a string that you want...

For more information please add the code...

Comment: Updated w/new code. Your approach works for a straight UITableView. But this is for a CoreData context receiving new data, and the NSFetchedResultsController is calling configureCell. I don't know how to differentiate between cell types (NormalCell,SpecialCell) inside ConfigureCell